# Usiung border on QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, border, qwebview

I'm trying to change the `QWebView` border just as I do with `QLineEdit`, setting the `QWebView` stylesheet for this:

```
QWebView
{
    border: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The border is just ignored. I've tried changing the background of it and it works alright.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a way of doing that?

There it is. Code and print that refers to `QWebView`.

```
materialViewer = new QWebView(Study);
materialViewer->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("materialViewer"));
materialViewer->setGeometry(QRect(190, 10, 591, 531));
materialViewer->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
materialViewer->setUrl(QUrl("about:blank"));
materialViewer->setRenderHints( QPainter::Antialiasing |
                                QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing | 
                                QPainter::NonCosmeticDefaultPen |
                                QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform |
                                QPainter::TextAntialiasing );
```

Link: http://imageshack.us/f/684/semttulomym.png/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screen shot of exactly what you are seeing, maybe also provide a complete code listing for the screen shot. I suggest you do so by first reducing the code the as little as possible to see this problem

Comment: Done. I just edited the post.

Comment: Year later in Qt 4.8.5 this bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

There it is. Code and print that refers to QWebView.

```
  materialViewer = new QWebView(Study);
    materialViewer->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("materialViewer"));
    materialViewer->setGeometry(QRect(190, 10, 591, 531));
    materialViewer->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
    materialViewer->setUrl(QUrl("about:blank"));
    materialViewer->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing|QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing|QPainter::NonCosmeticDefaultPen|QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform|QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
```

Link: http://imageshack.us/f/684/semttulomym.png/

Comment: is this an image of the problem you are trying to solve, or of the solution?

Comment: I should edit the post with that. I was going to do that, but i forgot, sorry.